# Selenium WebDriver - Not able to Select Drop down with onchange Script

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver, css-selectors

How do i select a drop down has a attributes like below in Selenium WebDriver. Element are located with cssSelector.

Once any option in drop down is selected from the dropdown, the page refresh with new contents.

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="testproject" style="font-size:80%;position:relative; top:-1px;" >

<option title="A" value="1"> A</option>
<option title="B" value="2"> B</option>
<option title="C" value="3"> C</option>
<option title="D" value="4"> D</option>
```

I tried with below option but unable to locate/select any option.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[name='testproject']")));
select.selectByVisibleText("C");
```

How to identify/select a option from the drop down. Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a cssselector, use **By.cssSelector** instead of **By.name**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='testproject']")));
```

If you want to use **By.name**, then use like this:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("testproject")));
```

**NOTE:- In both the cases above, I am assuming there is one element "select" with the class "testproject". But, if that's not the case then you have to use the first code for cssselector and change the code to ;**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='testproject']")));
```

Comment: Awesome.. If it has helped you, please mark it as answer and/or upvote it so that others facing similar problem will relate to it. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Sorry..... I was unable to select the dropdown with Select     select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='testproject']")));

Comment: getting exception as ----------- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name*='testproject']"}

Comment: Are there multiple **select** elements with name attribute as **"testproject"**
 ?

Comment: No there is only one. But the issue may be is with onchange="this.form.submit(); ---------because page refresh once we select a value from dropdown. i.e page selection + submit -----please help.

Comment: May be you have to wait for the element.. Try this code before executing above code for selecting the element from dropdown:
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[name='testproject']")));`

Comment: By appending the above code for **wait** before selecting the element, did it work for you? @user3875635